# PHP: Custom Designed URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

Im trying to send users to custom url's based on their profile information. Instead of sending a user to **www.website.com/profile/john.doe** i want to send them to **www.website.com/john.doe** - however when i try remove the "profile" portion of the url. I get an error saying

```
The john.doe_controller.php file could not be found.
```

unless im understanding wrong, i dont want to create a new controller file for every user. is there a .htaccess rule i could use for this.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Checkout mod rewrite, or use routing

Comment: What's your htaccess ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code in Root/.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /profile/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use below rule in your root `.htaccess` file:-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Hope it will help you :)